# Частица "то" после личных местоимений

Tags: орфография, частицы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, ставится ли дефис после личных местоимений перед частицей "то"? Например: "Я-то знаю, что она меня любит". Или: "Я то знаю, что она меня любит". Как правильно?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

> "Я-то знаю, что она меня любит". Или: "Я то знаю, что она меня любит". Как правильно?

Оба варианта возможны. Смысл у них несколько разный.

В первом случае "то" - действительно частица. И как частица она требует дефиса.

***"Я-то знаю, что она меня любит"*** = именно я знаю, не кто-то.

Во втором случае "то" - местоимение.

***"Я то знаю, что она меня любит"*** = (я знаю то, ...) = я знаю именно это.

Второй вариант встречается редко, но в принципе возможен. ***В остальных случаях "то" - частица и пишется с дефисом, независимо от части речи, которую она усиливает, это может быть любая часть речи, в т. ч. и местоимение.***

В отношении неопределенных местоимений и наречий (см. KseniaK) типа "кто-то" и "где-то". Сейчас нет единого мнения, та ли это частица в них входит, и частица ли вообще, есть мнение что это *суффикс*. Подробности опускаю, ибо сам не силен, но предупредить о том не лишне. Могу найти, если интересно. Но на правописании это никак не сказывается.

Comment: Спасибо за полноценный ответ!:)

Answer (score 0):

Дефис ставится:

-ТО, частица. 1. Употр. для подчёркивания и выделения в предложении слова, к которому относится. Я-то понимаю. Ночь-то какая тёплая! Слушать-то слушал, да ничего не понял. Где-то он сейчас? Что дальше-то делать будешь? 2. Входит в состав неопределённых местоимений и наречий. Кто-то звонит. Что-то упало со стола. Какой-то человек вошёл в дом. Когда-то слышала об этом. Где-то потерял очки. Куда-то убежали. Почему-то плачет. 3. Употр. после местоименных слов вместо конкретного указания на перечисляемые предметы, действия или признаки. Рассказывает: был там-то и там-то, делал то-то и то-то, встречался с теми-то.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ!!!